# Send computed data from client to server

Tags: json, rest

i have created simple REST architecture using Jersey and Tomcat. I sent data from server (as a resource using "/get") to client and then customer makes some computation on this data. My problem is, how to send this calculated data from client to server ?

Comment: So i have a connection in one side, but i need in both sides.

Comment: Just send the data with another `POST` or `PUT` HTTP request.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using a REST architecture, how to send the data back to the server depends on what this data represents.

For example, suppose you are dealing with users, a GET on `/users` is performed, so the client has the data, now

- if the client changes something you might want to make it PUT on `/users/:userid`, the PUT here represents the fact that you are updating a user identified by `userid`
- if the client does not find a user it might want to create it, so you might want it to perform a POST on `/users` with the user in the payload

This is just an example to briefly explain how it works, of course it depends on your case, if you need more help please update your answer adding details.

Comment: i add details.. but don't know how use PUT